# iphone - change pointer reference to a new object and clean old

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
MyClass *obj1 = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[myArray addObject: obj1];
```

How to clean the old obj1 reference here, if I want to reuse the variable name. Without destroying anything in the array.

```
obj1 = nil 

OR

[obj1 release];
```

// What is the differences?

```
obj1 = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[myArray addObject: obj1];
```

........... 
Continue using obj1 and add in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add an object to array, array stores the variable address, so you can freely use your temporary variable(`obj1`) to create another object - the value in the array won't be destroyed.

But since array retains its elements for proper memory management you need to release `obj1` after pushing it to array. So you need `[obj1 release];` line

Answer (score 2):

Assigning `nil` to the variable has no effect. You need to call `release` to ensure that the old object gets properly cleaned up.

BTW, reusing variable names within a block a of code is usually a bad idea.

Comment: If I am going to add some sample constant object in the array, I am reluctant to use obj1, obj2 ... that's why. Thanks for the answer. 1up.

Comment: Without knowing the details of your code, all I can say is that it isn't *always* a bad idea, just *usually*. Thanks for the vote. :-)